# multiple-value-bind discard first value

Tags: common-lisp

In my code below , I only want r.

```
(let* ((frac  (multiple-value-bind (f r)  (floor amt  100) r)))
..use frac..)
```

I get compilation warnings saying unused variable f.

Is there an idiomatic way of writing this?

Comment: What's the intent of the code you have there?

Comment: A warning isn't necessarily an error so it should work. It's nice that the compiler warns since it could be a bug.

Comment: Some implementations allow `*`, `**`, `***` etc as names that indicate an unused variable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`declare ignore` is generally useful in this context, here:

```
(multiple-value-bind (_ frac)  (floor amt 100)
  (declare (ignore _))
  ; use frac)
```

Answer (score 9):

NTH-VALUE allows you to choose one of a form's return values. This will behave like your snippet:

```
(let* ((frac (nth-value 1 (floor amt 100))))
  ...)
```